# How can I make a registration bot in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I want to do registrations using dialogflow. For example: I want bot to ask following questions:

What's your name?
What's your email?

and so on.

I tried to implement this but not able to manage intents properly. What should I do to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Was there anything specific that you weren't able to accomplish with the intents? The question is quite broad at the moment.

Comment: Could you specify which Dialogflow service you are using, [CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs) or [ES](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs)? What challenges were you facing? You may also try to start with one of the prebuilt agents ([ES](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-prebuilt)/[CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agents-prebuilt)) to help you to get started. For CX, you may try “Order and account management” prebuilt agent and check the “Address Collection” flow. For ES, you may try “User Name” prebuilt agent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to add the training phrases and then extract the entities for the names & email ids. Once it's done, you need to add the prompts and the follow-up chatbot messages in the Bot reply order.

In Dialogflow ES, go to the intent > add training phrases > extract the name, email ids by clicking on the particular words and it will be reflected in the 'Action and parameter' section then add the prompts.

[image]

In Dialogflow CX, go to the Build > flow section > select the route of your intent > select the intent > add training phrases and extract the names, email ids then add prompts to be displayed by the chatbot.

[image]

Here's an example - how it will be displayed

[image]

If you need any more info, please refer to the following [doc](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/integrate-dialogflow-cx-bot-website/) for more details.